# Can I import teabags into the United States?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, food-and-drink

I'm going to the US through SFO from Europe (Germany to France to US) and would like to bring loose teabags of British Yorkshire Tea. They are not packed like they were for sales, but rather in Tupperware because I buy them in big boxes. This might look a little suspicious I believe, and I don't want to get in trouble.

Comment: Re-package it in a bag labeled "Pipe Tobacco", and it should be permitted... (just make sure it's labeled with a country of origin other than Cuba)  ;)

Comment: I've brought duffel bags of tea back with me from China (my wife's family has a tea farm). The tea was packaged into opaque bags about 8g each, for a total of about 5kg. I declared I had food and went through the serious scan, the person operating the scanner said that tea is not food and had no problems with it.

Comment: @200 this question is way older and has actually been mentioned on the other one as well. But the other one does have a more detailed answer, and even by Mr Lipton.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Depends on the tea, check [the US Customs and Border Protection's help page](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/335/~/importing-coffee,-tea-or-spices-for-personal-use). Seems forbidden if the tea contains fruit or vegetable leaves or seeds, including citrus leaves or seeds. But otherwise okay for personal use. But you might want to double check.

Comment: "Tea- commercially packaged and ready to be boiled, steeped or microwaved in liquid." is listed under the things generally admissible.

Comment: Loose leaf tea is prohibited. Packaged tea bags should be fine, as per [this document](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/82/related/1/session/L2F2LzEvc2lkL0pmNDNLOXls/~/importing-coffee%2C-tea-or-spices-for-personal-use)

Comment: That document says loose *citrus* leaves are prohibited. Loose leaf tea (in a package) is acceptable.