# Would I be allowed to get on a plane from the UK and fly to America with tea?

Tags: usa, uk, customs-and-immigration, health, food-and-drink

Today I was doing some research on food and drinks and realised that tea is not a very big thing in The U.S. and that all the *"good"* brands of tea are extremely overpriced or quite *"unattractive"*.

So I thought I'd take a box (or two) with me to The U.S, but unfortunately the TSA *might* confiscate my tea and I may have to throw it away before I'm allowed to enter the country.

Would I be allowed to get on a plane from the UK and fly to The U.S. with tea?
If not are there rules and regulations on shipping tea to The U.S. and would I be allowed to do it?

NOTE: when I say `tea` I mean `Tea bags` and `Loose Leaf Tea`.

Comment: Tea is a much bigger thing in America than it used to be. You may not be able to get the brands you are used to, and you will probably have better luck at specialty tea shops than in supermarkets.

Comment: @GayotFow It wasn't about the tax, it was about the representation in Parliament, or rather the utter lack thereof. Though that event is the primary reason tea remains less popular in the United States than elsewhere in the world. Even so, at this point it should be possible to find almost any sort of tea you want...

Comment: @MichaelHampton I'm sort of like the OP in that I carry a supply of tea bags and spares for the pilot if there is one. I must have flown between here and NYC somewhere in the 3 digits range, and have never given tea bags a second thought until now. So I'm very keen to lurk on this page and see what the answers are.

Comment: @GayotFow They will only try to make tea with cold salt water.

Comment: related (duplicate?): [Can I import teabags into the United States?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/19840/12011) Granted, this one already has a more conclusive answer (from Mr. Lipton, no less.)

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan I think the requirement to seek out a specialty tea shop rather than popping down to the local corner shop for a decent brew is already a step too far.

Comment: I finally understood the dire tea situation in the US on one occasion when I split the water they gave me over myself, and it *didn't even hurt*. That being the case it really doesn't matter how good or bad the tea leaves are.

Comment: My stepson has brought over a few of the extra-large boxes of PG Tips and large jars of Bovril for me each time he's visited over the last few years without any issues. I don't know for sure if he declared them or not though ...

Comment: What do you mean by "not a very big thing"?  Not as big as some places sure, but it's pretty big and we have a TON of relatively low cost options even in local supermarkets.  Might be missing out on higher end stuff though.

Comment: You can get a variety of teas at almost all stores selling ethnic Indian and Chinese groceries.

Comment: Americans drink tons of tea.  We just drink ~85% of it iced instead of hot.

Comment: @Kevin +1, though I daresay the tea from which American iced tea is brewed would not meet Mango's standards for "good" tea.

Comment: @GayotFow I don't think Uncle Sam would appreciate that ;)

Comment: @phoog I thought Iced tea was just "cold tea"?

Comment: @Mango sure, but you can make cold tea using high-quality tea leaves and you can make it using low-quality tea leaves.  If you are concerned about a lack of *high-quality, affordable* tea in the US, I don't think the abundance of iced tea will help with that.  In my experience, most iced tea is crappy tea, with its crappiness somewhat masked by overabundant amounts of sugar and artificial lemon flavor.

Comment: Sure you can bring some tea, but don't be surprised if you "lose your baggage", in the harbor or something.

Comment: I brought Chinese tea to the US and I showed it to the customs officer.  They told me it's alright.  (Braised) eggs on the other hand were not alright, even though vacuum sealed with the label on.

Comment: @Szabolcs Meat can only be imported into the US if it is still packaged and stamped with its country of origin, and that country is certified by the government to be free of certain livestock diseases. Already-cooked meat in a meal will almost never be allowed in.

Comment: @SteveJessop the temperature of the water has to do with a certain incident regarding McDonalds Coffee a number of years back, and nothing to do with how hot people think the water should ideally be.

Comment: @TylerH Yes, I know that now.  I just wanted to let the OP know that the customs officer approved of the tea.  Others quoted the regulations, yet others talked about bringing tea in the past, but no one talked about showing the tea at customs.  So it was a small piece of new information.

Comment: @LindaJeanne: I'm not sure that's strictly true, since allegedly major chains in the US (including McDonald's itself) actually continued to serve coffee hot even after the Liebeck ruling. But anyway, unless you give the customer a kettle, any means of serving tea where you give them the tea and the water separately is doomed to failure. It all depends whether your customers would rather decide for themselves how long to brew their tea in lukewarm water, or trust the server and have it done in hot water. If necessary for health and safety, the tea could be cooled *after* brewing.

Comment: The Bostonians didn't throw away *all* the tea; for example, New York still sells tea... sometimes. Just don't fly to Boston if you want a Tea Party. ;)

Comment: You can get good quality tea in the US. Try a health-food-type grocery store. They tend to have quality tea, both bagged and loose.

Comment: @phoog I like to say that American Tea is just water soaked in dirty leaves...

Comment: British problems. 'Nuff said.

Answer (score 59):

You'll certainly be allowed to get on a plane in the UK with the tea, but you'll have to declare it to Customs and may have it examined by an agricultural specialist, who will decide whether it is allowed in.

Here's [US Customs and Border Protection on importing tea](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/335/~/importing-coffee,-tea-or-spices-for-personal-use):

> There are no restrictions on the importation of coffee, tea or spices
>   for personal use, although they may be subject to Animal and Plant
>   Health Inspection Service (APHIS) and  Food and Drug Administration
>   (FDA) inspections if a Customs and Border Protection (CBP) Officer
>   suspects contamination or insect infestation of the product.  For more
>   information from FDA call 1-888-723-3366. Contact FDA.
>
> **Please note that tea or spices containing fruit or vegetable leaves or
>   seeds, including citrus leaves or seeds, are typically prohibited.**

On the plane, you'll be given a [Customs declaration form](http://www.cbp.gov/sites/default/files/assets/sample6059B_0.jpg) to fill out. On that form, it will ask if you are bringing in any plants, seeds, food, etc... Always declare any food or agricultural items you are bringing into the country. You can be fined for failure to declare. Someone from CBP may ask to see the tea, and there's a chance you won't be allowed to bring it in, but you shouldn't be otherwise penalized as long as you've declared it.

You'll likely have more success with commercially packaged tea rather than a random unmarked bag of loose leaf.

Comment: A tea answer from Zach **Lipton**?

Comment: @AndrewLazarus [http://s3media.247sports.com/Uploads/Assets/478/257/6_3257478.png](http://s3media.247sports.com/Uploads/Assets/478/257/6_3257478.png)

Comment: Source: my last name

Comment: "You'll likely have more success with commercially packaged tea rather than a random unmarked bag of loose leaf." There is no doubt about it. You will have much more success with sealed, commercially packaged tea. If there are large quantities involved (greater quantities than personal use), import taxes could be involved, but according to the post I don't foresee this being a difficulty.

Comment: I love the fact that pest control is handled by APHIS!

Comment: @TomAnderson greater quantities than for personal use would fall under the $100 gift exemption.  A quick look at the internet suggests that one could bring around 5000 tea bags without exceeding the exemption, though I grant that I made this calculation using the price of Tesco Original Full Flavoured Quality Blend Medium Strength Tea, which may not be considered among the "'good' brands of tea."

Comment: @ZachLipton thank you for the detailed description now I know that I can no longer bring `lemon & ginger`, `winter spice` or `cinnamon and cherry` :(

Comment: Well, it's "are typically prohibited." If they're in sealed commercial boxes, they may well let you bring them in (nobody's ever looked at my tea long enough to see whether it's citrus or not), but there's no real guarantee, just as long as you're prepared to be told no.

Comment: I'll just point out that, in this question, **Mango** is interested in importing fruity teas here.

Comment: I just _need_ to know if your last name is coincidental

Comment: @Insane That's the kind of mystique I like to inspire! I will say that it did not occur to me when deciding to answer this question.

Comment: I agree with @ZachLipton's comment. Having entered the U.S. by air more times than I can remember, here is what is likely to happen. You check the box that says you have food. The border patrol officer will ask you what kind of food you have. You say tea. Usually that will be the end of it. It's possible they'll ask to see it, and when you show them your sealed commercial package of tea they will let you go. I can't guarantee that it won't get confiscated, but you won't get in trouble if you declared it.

Comment: Last time I brought food in through JFK, they sent me to an "agricultural specialist." That guy wanted to chat randomly about video editing for like five minutes until a couple came along with various spices and other foods from Afghanistan. He suddenly became quite interested in them and sent me on my way without ever looking at my food.

Comment: @ZachLipton not **just** fruity teas :D

Comment: @Mango if you have a bunch of boxes of sealed commercially packaged tea and one happens to be a citrus blend, I'd say you likely have a decent shot depending on the whims of whoever you're talking to. That stuff has likely been heat treated and could be admissible anyway, but you don't have the paperwork to prove it. Don't bring anything you aren't prepared to part with, but I'd probably do it.

Answer (score 16):

I have brought commercially packaged tea into the USA on numerous occasions without any incident. Didn't want to leave a half-empty box to be thrown out by the hotel maids.

On the other hand, I can not imagine why the OP thinks that tea is not a big deal in the United States. There are at least three high-end tea shops in Berkeley, California alone. ([Site](https://www.teance.com/), [Site](http://www.farleaves.com/), no relationship other than infrequent customer.) Most brands of tea I have seen marketed in the UK are available here; if the OP has a particular preference I can look.

A distinctive brand of tea will be useful if you are [kidnapped](https://www.criterion.com/current/posts/1081-the-lady-vanishes-tea-and-treachery) by Fascist agents, though.

Comment: While you *can get* brands of tea that claim to be the same, at specialist places like World Market and such, odds are that you won't find a reliable source of tea that tastes as you are accustomed until you've been here a whole (few years maybe). So bring a good stash of comfort drinks.

Comment: Andrew thanks and hopefully I won't get kidnapped by Fascists.

Comment: @DewiMorgan I might have to bring a ton of boxes.

Comment: What Dewi says.  I found that when I lived in the US, close to Harvard Square, whilst I could get all sorts of specialist teas (oolong, darjeeling, assam, etc.) of excellent quality very easily, I couldn't find a convincing "cuppa" anywhere, a problem that remained until my local supermarket starting importing PG Tips tea bags.  What the American tea market refers to as "*English breakfast blend*" would not, in my experience, suffice.

Comment: PG Tips is available in the USA from that small specialist retailer, Costco.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus I doubt many tourists will find Costco a viable option since they will be unlikely to have a membership, or be inclined to pay the fee to join.

Comment: @phoog One of my friends who is already a Costco member wants to go to a Costco in every country that has one. He believes he lacks only Mexico!

Comment: The Hyacinth Bucket in me makes me cringe at the term "tea shop". The more traditional term in Britain is a ['teahouse'](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/teahouse) or ['tearoom'](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tearoom). Although according to Wiktionary that could be misconstrued in America as it is aparently (somewhat dated) slang.

Comment: Berkeley is... not typical of the USA. Now, it's probably pretty easy to get hold of decent quality tea in most decent-sized cities in the US, but attempting to extrapolate from Berkeley is likely to lead to misleading results.

Answer (score 10):

**I always tell my relatives to bring their own teabags when they visit.** There have been no issues whatever about this; customs officials think this perfectly normal for visitors from the UK, and may even look askance at those who do not.

Tea is HUGE here. You can get Earl Grey with lavender accents and snobby French teas that even the French can't pronounce and things done with "'erbs" and fruit that don't even have any connection with the tea plant and white tea and green tea and it's all served iced, with or without ice, or hot in a glass, probably with lemon on the side. Ask for milk in it, and people will look at you like you just drop-kicked a kitten, but if you're lucky they might be able to find a sachet of powdered non-dairy creamer that's normally used for coffee.

"A mug, white, with one" has no meaning here in the US, because the incredible range of things they call tea precludes any such simplicity. Even being able to find plain black tea (which is what most Brits expect when we say "tea") will be a challenge, as most places don't even stock the stuff.

While you can get brands of tea that claim to be the same, at specialist places like World Market and such, odds are that you won't find a reliable source of tea that tastes as you are accustomed until you've been here a while (few years maybe).

Mostly, they're as much the "same" as cola canned in the UK, US, and middle east are the "same", which is to say, they have the same logo on the box but there it ends.

So bring a good stash of your own comfort drinks.

Also, bring a travel kettle that can work on 120v. Not only do most hotels not have a kettle in each room, but it's hard to find an electric kettle that actually works for any reasonable amount of money.

And don't use tap water to make the tea. I know, "don't drink the water" is so hackneyed travel advice, it's become a trope. But either buy bottled water, or get a very good water filter (which, thankfully, they DO sell here). Mains water is typically laced with chlorine and fluoride *by law*, to the point that you step out of the shower smelling olike you just stepped out of a swimming pool. So you will meet *many* Americans with thyroid issues (I never even knew thyroids existed, beyond a vague "heard the name", before I came to the US), and none of them have any clue why. Most assume it's genetic.

*TL;DR:* **Don't drink the water. Bring tea bags. Bring a 120v kettle.** And be prepared for the fact that the toilet paper is both a different shape, and not up to BSI Kitemark standards. Frankly, you might as well wipe your arse on a teabag. But that's another rant, for another time.

And don't get me started on the plumbing.

Comment: What's an "erb"?

Comment: The h on herb and herbal is not typically pronounced in most US regions. Though any generalisation about the US is doomed to fail; as each state is like a nation unto itself, with its own dialect and customs.

Comment: Wherever I travel I take my own teabags and a little immersion heater. When entering the US I declare my tea and get a tired smile from the Customs bods.

Comment: OK, I finally joined Travel.SE just so I could +1 for the "drop kicked a kitten" remark. However, I'm not sure which look you're going for - some will look at you in horror, other will cheer wildly!

Comment: Ok, if I had realized that "erbs" was "herbs" I wouldn't have commented.  Interestingly, "drop kick" remains in the US lexicon despite the fact that the move is virtually obsolete in American football.  @FreeMan I (hope I) have never met anyone who would cheer anyone for drop-kicking a kitten.  Who would do such a thing?

Comment: Indeed, the 'h' is silent in correct American English. Incidentally, it was also the original pronunciation. Brits beginning to pronounce the 'h' is a relatively recent development.

Comment: @phoog 'Dropkick' is also [a wrestling maneuver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dropkick).

Comment: @phoog there are many people who don't like cats. Some would go so far as to drop kick them or use them as target practice. There are even [some Brits](https://youtu.be/grbSQ6O6kbs?t=50s) who aren't fond of them! :)

Comment: @reirab it's also, apparently in at least one instance, [a soccer maneuver](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z00R0l5u7nA).  But how do you define "original"? The H was of course pronounced in very early (prehistoric?) Latin, after all.

Comment: `Don't drink the water.` I'm no American, but perhaps you meant *city* water? Some city water's a little off, but usually it's fine. This answer sounds like a rant about how to travel to the US.

Comment: If they have their own well, then yeah, probably it won't have stuff in it (so long as there's no fracking going on nearby). Other than that, what water is there, other than the municipal supply? We don't normally go down to the nearest river with a bucket. You're right that supplies vary widely, but the chlorine smell when running the tap is strong in most regions I've visited, until I got used to it after a couple of years, then it stopped smelling any more.

Comment: @cat certainly avoid the water in Flint. Most cities have far cleaner water with, as Dewi notes, fairly heavy chlorination. One reason for this, as compared to Europe, is the weather. When I lived in Virginia, I could tell a lot about the weather from the strength of the smell in my morning shower. It's much warmer in most of the US than in most of Europe, on average. But a basic charcoal filter will get rid of the chlorine smell.

Comment: @phoog Even the extent of water problems in Flint [is a bit overstated](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/32109/21543). While I prefer filtered water (more to get rid of the minerals than the chlorine and fluoride,) the "don't drink the water" stance here is rather overstated. Apparently [quite](http://www.cdc.gov/fluoridation/pdf/pollick.pdf) [a lot](http://www.cdc.gov/fluoridation/) [of experts](http://www.who.int/water_sanitation_health/oralhealth/en/index2.html) disagree with the assertions made here regarding fluoridation.

Comment: @reirab I haven't seen any assertions here regarding fluoridation, other than that US water contains it, which is true, and a fact to which I attribute my excellent dental health. The "overstated" link seems to be talking about lead levels in children's blood, rather than in the water, but little mention is made of lead paint, which is a far more important source of lead than drinking water.

Comment: @phoog I was referring to the part in the third-to-last paragraph about it causing thyroid problems, which CDC, WHO, and many others seem to assert that it does not. This post literally says "don't drink the water" in the U.S., which is silly at best. Regarding Flint, you're right that the measurements were referring to blood lead levels, but that's the point. Hysteria over alleged "lead poisoning" from the water is a bit absurd when blood lead levels are near an all-time low (since records began) in the affected population.

Comment: My main point is: don't drink the water *because it tastes awful*. It will most likely not cause health issues for any vacationer. Whether drinking bleach and fluoride causes thyroid problems in the long term is debatable, and fairly off-topic for the OP's question. On the other hand, that these elements make the water taste so awful it should not be drunk by anyone who wants a decent cup of tea is simply a matter of fact.

Comment: Every city in the US gets its water from a different source, and as a result there are *huge* variations in the taste.  Talking about how "the water" tastes in the US is like talking about how "the food" tastes in India.  Maybe you didn't like the water where you were, and that's fine, but don't assume it's the same throughout the country. The water in Oakland tastes completely different from that in San Francisco.

Comment: @NateEldredge I agree completely. I find tapwater quality varies drastically from town to town. I'm no connoisseur, I can't even tell the difference between Coke and Pepsi, so differences even I can notice must be drastic: I shouldn't be able to smell water being poured, from across the room. Some towns are, as you say, OK, but since there's no way to establish what the local water tastes like ahead of the time, the best policy for a decent cup of tea when traveling remains: bring your own tea bags, travel kettle and water filter.

Comment: Can you provide us with examples of snobby French teas that even the French can't pronounce?

Comment: @Estey Argh. Frustrating. I know that I put that specific phrase in as a reference to something I'd been ranting about only minutes before I wrote the post. But I haven't a clue what, and can't for the life of me find any reference to it in the usual places, such as SE and my wife's tea stash. Probably it was some "tisanne" (pronounced sort of like "tuh-ZAHN" in the US, but "ti-zAnn" in France)... but which one would I be ranting about? I don't know, I'm sorry.

Comment: @DewiMorgan It's alright. If this train of thoughts of yours comes back on track don't hesitate to let me know because this has really got me thinking.

Answer (score 7):

This answer was too long for a comment but it just a combination of Zach's and Andrew's answer.

You shouldn't have a problem bringing in "packages" of tea. Try to stick with a sealed, store bought, container. An unopened box, with that plastic film around it for example. It will come down to the discretion of customs people rather your tea looks suspect or not. Tea bags in a sealed box, wrapped in plastic. Probably not going to be an issue. Loose leaves in a ziplock baggie, rolling around in your carry on..... might be a problem.  Technically your only real concern is going to be some over-zealous customs personal or maybe a TSA agent that is really just clueless.  In all honestly, no one will probably even look at it.

Different states have different rules. Usually though this is only going to be an issue if you bring an entire suit-case full of tea. Some states require that anyone carrying any kind of fruit or agricultural product stop and declare it. Again I have never seen this used to stop a person from carrying a "normal" amount of tea. I have however seen this used to stop a person from carrying single units of fruit. So you may want to be aware of that too.

Let me stop and be clear at this point. In both cases listed above, I don't really see how you could get in trouble for carrying tea. I don't even get how someone would even know, under normal circumstances. That said, weird things can happen and an agent who is on a power trip (happens a lot more then it should) may just give you hard time over it. Avoid metal containers though.  Your problem, if you have one will probably come from; "Hey that guy has a bomb in his luggage, no wait it's just tea, well find some way to hassle him over it."

Next point however is that you should consider just getting your tea here. If you're going to a rural area you may need to stop in town on your way, but most cities will have what ever kind of tea you want at normally sane prices. If you know someone where you are going ask them to look around for you ahead of time. Big box stores may not have what you want, but there are usually tea shops around that certainly would.

Comment: Want to be super clear that your official tea "problems" are going to come from idiot officials, or officials trying to  give you a problem and under normal circumstances there shoudn't be any kind of an issue.

Comment: "Different states have different rules." Source? Border checks are performed by USDA and CBP, which are federal agencies abiding by federal law and regulation. AFAIK, their rules don't differ from one state to another (exception: transfer between Hawaii and the mainland is controlled by USDA to prevent migration of agricultural pests/diseases.) Enforcement might differ from one _agent_ to another, but the rules should be the same across the entire U.S.

Comment: Just a small note, the federal government is responsible for customs and immigration - so no matter what the state policy is, its the federal regulations that come into play with respect to import of goods into the US.

Comment: Different states have different rules for foods and CBP acts accordingly. http://www.cbp.gov/travel/us-citizens/know-before-you-go/prohibited-and-restricted-items "Bringing fruits and vegetables depends on a number of factors.... Whether or not CBP will allow the [example item] into the United States **depends on where you got it and where you are going after you arrive in the United States**". On the other hand, "As a general rule, condiments, vinegars, oils, packaged spices, honey, coffee and tea are admissible." Thus, the CBP inspects based on rules of a destination state, but not for tea.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid - The way that works is All Federal laws are applied then additional state laws are applied. You have to deal with both. I don't know of any state that gets upset over tea.

Comment: @coteyr Boston might :-D

Comment: California still has some [agricultural checkpoints](https://www.cdfa.ca.gov/plant/pe/ExteriorExclusion/borders_map.html) at the state borders.

Comment: @mkennedy If they're like the ones I've seen in other states, you can just drive right on past them if you're not driving a large truck full of agricultural products. They're certainly not going to know (or care) whether you have tea in your car.

Comment: @mkennedy I went through one of those in a car and was just waved through; didn't even come to a complete stop.

Comment: @reirab I suspect that the things you've seen in other states were not agricultural checkpoints. As far as I know only California and Hawaii have inspectors enforcing restrictions on agricultural imports.  The CA border checkpoints I've seen were constructed like toll booths; one could only drive *through* them, not past them. Other states commonly have weigh stations for commercial vehicles by the side of the highway, which have a different function (and are not always near the border). I suspect you're thinking of those.

Comment: @phoog [No, I'm thinking of these](http://www.freshfromflorida.com/Business-Services/Agricultural-Inspection-Stations). They are constructed similarly to weigh stations, but they're agricultural checkpoints.

Comment: @reirab well the last time I drove into Florida was in 1988 or so, and I don't remember whether those existed then or I just ignored them because passenger cars don't need to stop at them. Regardless, back to your original comment, CA stations *aren't* like these in that passenger cars *do* need to stop. I had a houseplant confiscated at one once. I-15

https://goo.gl/maps/JeJBRaXzcro

Comment: FL has strict rules about importing citrus fruit, firewood, and exporting "Spanish moss" that I am aware of.  Breaking one of these laws is can be a huge fine. It's law to stop at argi. station even in a car if your caring "agricultural, horticultural or livestock products"   Rental cars especially have to stop.  Again, tea isn't a problem in FL., unless your carrying a huge quantity. Also keep in mind that enforcement may be pretty lax for private individuals.

Answer (score 6):

I've never had any problems bringing back packaged loose leaf tea from Sweden or Austria. I've made the trip three times, and not once has customs asked to examine my tea. (They confiscated a single orange once though.) As one poster said, you will need to fill out a form on the plane declaring your items, but as long as you aren't bringing a boatload of tea, you should be fine. (My most recent trip had me bringing home approx. 2.5 pounds of Swedish tea.)

As an aside that doesn't answer the question... Yes, most readily available, loose leaf, American tea is horribly, horribly overpriced. I don't know about tea from the UK, but tea from Sweden is amazingly good compared to the two major tea stores I know here in Boston.

Comment: I was about to write an answer pretty much identical to this one (just without the two words "or Austria"); so far I haven't been able to find any place in the us that sells Söderte.

Comment: @IQAndreas Try searching for Soderblandning instead. [You](http://annateashop.com/product/soderblandning-tea/) [may](http://www.thenordicshop.net/soderblandning-swedish-tea-large.html) [get lucky.](http://www.ingebretsens.com/foods/beverages/soderblandning-tea.html) But be prepared to pay through the nose!

Comment: @IQAndreas http://www.theteacentre.se/  They ship to the U.S., and, up until recently, their prices were MUCH more reasonable than what I could find here. If you buy a lot of tea, or split an order with friends/family/coworkers (or are obsessed with good tea) the shipping fees start to become reasonable. At one point, even with overseas shipping fees, it was still cheaper to buy through them than through Tealuxe or Teavana. They were starting to raise their prices the last time I ordered, so it may not be the same now, but it can't hurt to look! They're where I buy my söderblandning from. :)

Answer (score 6):

As a concrete datapoint, I have flown at least three times into the US where a full suitcase contained (branded, packaged) Argentinean *yerba mate*, say some 25kg. I declared it, the bag was opened but not the packages,  and nothing happened.

Comment: Were you a US resident at the time?  The value of the customs exemption is dramatically different depending on this fact.

Comment: Nope. Canadian, on transit. The value in the whole suitcase was around $100, so I doubt it would trigger any fees. In any case, the TSA opened the suitcase (they leave a note  about it) both when transiting directly to Canada, and when flying a domestic leg.

Comment: Your bags weren't inspected by customs officials; the TSA doesn't do customs inspections.  They were just looking for bombs and the like.  The customs inspection happens after you claim your luggage, when you hand your blue customs form to the customs officer, and only if the customs officer decides to inspect you.  They usually don't.

Comment: I can confirm this. We regularly bring in *erva mate* from Brazil with no trouble, just declaring it at customs as "tea".

Comment: @phoog You're right about the difference between TSA and customs inspections, but you go through both TSA and customs (and immigration) when transiting U.S. airports from international flights.

Comment: @reirab I don't deny that! I just find security inspections to be more than irrelevant in a discussion about whether carrying tea is allowed, unless there is some concern about the capacity for the tea to fuel a fire.  I found one YouTube video on the subject, which used an accelerant to ignite the tea leaves, and I suppose TSA would be more concerned with the accelerant than with the leaves themselves.  Another implication of my earlier comment that I probably should have made explicit: if you're subject to a customs inspection, you'll know it, since the inspection happens *in your presence.*

Answer (score 2):

My wife has brought tea from China many times.  The inspector doesn't care one bit when she declares "tea".  We have frequently gotten a suitcase inspection (common for travelers from China, even more common for ethnic Chinese travelers from China) and they have never cared about the tea, either.